# WebView Component doesn't handle style in a consistent manner

Tags: c#, wpf, webview, windows-phone-8.1

I cannot begin to understand how the Windows Phone 8.1 "WebView" Component handle styles. I display some very static HTML, nothing fancy, and I did not set any particular CSS style.

Nevertheless, the HTML Tags seem to be handled differently and show up each with a different size or sometimes even a different font.

Here are two examples. On the one on the left, the paragraph written very small is an imbricated pre/code block whereas on the image on the right, it is a simple HTML table.

```
<pre>
    <code>
    ...
    <code>
</pre>
```

This issue happens with a whole lot of tags, ul/li and blockquotes are doing the same for instance.

I tried handling them each with a CSS rule... which works, but requires different rules / font-size for each tag...

Any idea how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem. After several days investigation, I found the CSS style *-ms-text-size-adjust* is the cause.

By default, *-ms-text-size-adjust* is *auto*, and IE will scale the content with some algorithm (mainly the contents that can't wrap, like pre, table, etc, have smaller font size ). If you instead set *-ms-text-size-adjust* to other value (like 100%, 200%), the problem will disappear.

Comment: I don't think this is THE cause, but it definitely corrects the symptoms. I think it is not the cause because it wrecks some other parts of the styling. The line breaks for instance end up being way longer. But it'll do until a real fix comes from MS. I set it to 300% and it then produces the same size font as before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another method I found to fix this is to set the viewport with the following:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    ...
```

Comment: Very nice solution! Moreover, <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" /> was enough for me.